# how to fix error in ggplot using geom_point null

Tags: r, ggplot2, graph, geom-point

pretty much what it says. i cant seem to create my scatterplot with the code that my prof basically hand fed to us

```
ggplot(df1, aes(mean, y)) +
geom_point() +
geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = lwr, ymax = upr, xmin = left, xmax = right))
```

the error message says this

```
Error in `geom_point()`:
! Problem while computing aesthetics.
ℹ Error occurred in the 1st layer.
Caused by error in `FUN()`:
! `data` must be uniquely named but has duplicate columns
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! As the error message is telling you, your data contains columns with the same name. To make your code work you have to make the column names unique, e.g. try `names(df1) <- make.unique(names(df1))`. Still, you should check which (and why some) columns have the same name. For more help please provide [a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) including a snippet of your data or some fake data best shared via `dput()`, ie.. run `dput(head(df1))` and copy the output into your post..

Comment: I agree with stefan's comment. I would add though that while `make.unique(.)` will fix the symptom, I'll emphasize a bit more stefan's note that *"you should check"* ... something in the previous processing of this data is either wrong (coder intent) or has failed to preserve unique names (bug or mis-use of function). Find whereever in your code path that created the non-unique names and fix that step, far far better than patching the symptom. Bottom line, while the error is from `ggplot2`, the problem is with the data, and we don't have that. Good luck!